# Padding a column of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, dataset

I have data in the the form of a table, whose one column is the following

```
{1.94238, 1.94361, 4.72888},
 {1.94477, 1.94938, 4.71431},
 {1.94893, 1.95817, 4.69017},
 {1.9551, 1.96907, 4.65627},
 {1.9637, 1.98115, 4.61168},
 {1.97539, 1.99357, 4.55427},
 {1.99141, 2.00535, 4.48002},
          {4.38177},
          {4.24668},
 {2.04454, 2.07149, 4.05151},
 {2.05173, 2.13016, 3.75524},
 {2.05838, 2.23059, 3.29844},
           {2.0636},
           {2.0672},
           {2.06916},
           {2.06951}
```

I want to pad the single elements from left and right with `Null` and bring the above into the following form

```
 {1.94238, 1.94361, 4.72888},
 {1.94477, 1.94938, 4.71431},
 {1.94893, 1.95817, 4.69017},
 {1.9551, 1.96907, 4.65627},
 {1.9637, 1.98115, 4.61168},
 {1.97539, 1.99357, 4.55427},
 {1.99141, 2.00535, 4.48002},
       {Null, Null, 4.38177},
       {Null, Null, 4.24668},
 {2.04454, 2.07149, 4.05151},
 {2.05173, 2.13016, 3.75524},
 {2.05838, 2.23059, 3.29844},
 {2.0636, Null, Null},
 {2.0672, Null, Null},
 {2.06916, Null, Null},
 {2.06951, Null, Null}
```

Comment: `PadLeft[list, Automatic, Null]` pads on the left with `Null`.

Comment: and `PadRight[list, Automatic, Null]` pads on the right. you need to provide the row number ( or the rule) to switch between left and right padding.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, just counting from 1, from the top. For instance, if this varies from column to column, is there then a generic rule to do such right and left padding? I mean if the row number containing the list to be padded varies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** We can define a conditional padding function `conditionalPad[test]` that pads on left or right depending on whether the two-argument function `test` evaluates to `True`. The two arguments of the input function `test` are the value and the index of a row element.

```
ClearAll[conditionalPad]
conditionalPad[test_] := Module[{l = Max[Length /@ #]}, 
    MapIndexed[If[test[#, #2[[1]]], 
       PadLeft[#, l, Null], 
       PadLeft[#, -l, Null]] &, #]] &;
```

With the  test function

```
t1 = #2 <= 10 &;
```

`conditionalPad[t1] @ list` replicates the first example in the original answer and Lee's example.

`conditionalPad[t2] @ list` where

```
t2 = MemberQ[leftpaddedrows, #2] &;
```

gives the same output as the second example.

With the test function

```
t3 = OddQ[#2] &;
```

we replicate sakra's example.

The test function `True&` pads on the left  (and `False&` pads on the right) unconditionally.

Additional examples where the test function depends only on a value of the row (`t4`), on both a value and index (`t5`) , on neither (`t6`) are

```
t4 = #[[1]] <= 3 &;
t5  = Abs[#[[1]] - #2] < 5 &
t6 = (Norm[Last /@ list] <= 3) &;
```

**Original answer:**

```
list = {{1.94238, 1.94361, 4.72888}, {1.94477, 1.94938, 
    4.71431}, {1.94893, 1.95817, 4.69017}, {1.9551, 1.96907, 
    4.65627}, {1.9637, 1.98115, 4.61168}, {1.97539, 1.99357, 
    4.55427}, {1.99141, 2.00535, 4.48002}, {4.38177}, {4.24668}, {2.04454, 2.07149, 
    4.05151}, {2.05173, 2.13016, 3.75524}, {2.05838, 2.23059, 
    3.29844}, {2.0636}, {2.0672}, {2.06916}, {2.06951}};
```

You can use [`PadLeft`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft.html) and [`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html):

```
list1 = PadLeft[list, Automatic, Null];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm[list1]
```

> $\tiny \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.94238 & 1.94361 & 4.72888 \\
>  1.94477 & 1.94938 & 4.71431 \\
>  1.94893 & 1.95817 & 4.69017 \\
>  1.9551 & 1.96907 & 4.65627 \\
>  1.9637 & 1.98115 & 4.61168 \\
>  1.97539 & 1.99357 & 4.55427 \\
>  1.99141 & 2.00535 & 4.48002 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 4.38177 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 4.24668 \\
>  2.04454 & 2.07149 & 4.05151 \\
>  2.05173 & 2.13016 & 3.75524 \\
>  2.05838 & 2.23059 & 3.29844 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 2.0636 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 2.0672 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 2.06916 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 2.06951 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Tow switch from left padding to right padding after row `t`:

```
t = 10;
list2 = list;
list2[[;; t]] = PadLeft[list2[[;; t]], Automatic, Null];
list2[[t + 1 ;;]] = PadRight[list2[[t + 1 ;;]], Automatic, Null];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm[list2]
```

> $\tiny \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.94238 & 1.94361 & 4.72888 \\
>  1.94477 & 1.94938 & 4.71431 \\
>  1.94893 & 1.95817 & 4.69017 \\
>  1.9551 & 1.96907 & 4.65627 \\
>  1.9637 & 1.98115 & 4.61168 \\
>  1.97539 & 1.99357 & 4.55427 \\
>  1.99141 & 2.00535 & 4.48002 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 4.38177 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 4.24668 \\
>  2.04454 & 2.07149 & 4.05151 \\
>  2.05173 & 2.13016 & 3.75524 \\
>  2.05838 & 2.23059 & 3.29844 \\
>  2.0636 & \text{Null} & \text{Null} \\
>  2.0672 & \text{Null} & \text{Null} \\
>  2.06916 & \text{Null} & \text{Null} \\
>  2.06951 & \text{Null} & \text{Null} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

To pad left at rows in the list `leftpaddedrows` and right at rows in the list `rightpaddedrows`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
leftpaddedrows = RandomSample[Range@Length@list, 10];
rightpaddedrows = Complement[Range[Length@list], leftpaddedrows];

list3 = list;
list3[[leftpaddedrows]] = PadLeft[list3[[leftpaddedrows]], Automatic, Null];
list3[[rightpaddedrows]] = PadRight[list3[[rightpaddedrows]], Automatic, Null];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm[list3]
```

> $\tiny \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1.94238 & 1.94361 & 4.72888 \\
>  1.94477 & 1.94938 & 4.71431 \\
>  1.94893 & 1.95817 & 4.69017 \\
>  1.9551 & 1.96907 & 4.65627 \\
>  1.9637 & 1.98115 & 4.61168 \\
>  1.97539 & 1.99357 & 4.55427 \\
>  1.99141 & 2.00535 & 4.48002 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 4.38177 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 4.24668 \\
>  2.04454 & 2.07149 & 4.05151 \\
>  2.05173 & 2.13016 & 3.75524 \\
>  2.05838 & 2.23059 & 3.29844 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 2.0636 \\
>  \text{Null} & \text{Null} & 2.0672 \\
>  2.06916 & \text{Null} & \text{Null} \\
>  2.06951 & \text{Null} & \text{Null} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 6):

Another approach if you want to left pad the first *n* one-element lists and right pad the rest is:

```
lst = {{1.94238, 1.94361, 4.72888}, {1.94477, 1.94938, 
   4.71431}, {1.94893, 1.95817, 4.69017}, {1.9551, 1.96907, 
   4.65627}, {1.9637, 1.98115, 4.61168}, {1.97539, 1.99357, 
   4.55427}, {1.99141, 2.00535, 
   4.48002}, {4.38177}, {4.24668}, {2.04454, 2.07149, 
   4.05151}, {2.05173, 2.13016, 3.75524}, {2.05838, 2.23059, 
   3.29844}, {2.0636}, {2.0672}, {2.06916}, {2.06951}}

padLen = Length /@ lst // Max;
```

Followed by calls to [SequenceReplace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceReplace.html?q=SequenceReplace):

```
nlst = SequenceReplace[lst, {{x_}} :> PadLeft[{x}, padLen, Null], 2];
alst = SequenceReplace[nlst, {{x_}} :> PadRight[{x}, padLen, Null]] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `MapThread` to specify a padding plan for each row, i.e.:

```
paddingPlan = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3};
MapThread[
   PadLeft[#1, #2, Null] &, 
   {list, paddingPlan}
]
```

The padding plan can also be generated programmatically. E.g., use alternating padding values for rows with an odd or even row index:

```
paddingPlan = Array[If[OddQ[#], 3, -3] &, Length@list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list /.{{x_/;IntegerPart[x]==4}:> {Null,Null,x}, {x_/;IntegerPart[x]==2}:> {x,Null,Null}}


% // MatrixForm
```

[image]